# SQL query not returning any data

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm having an issue with trying to return records that have two conditions which are not equal.

I have three tables: Person, Student, and Instructor. I'm trying to return a list of persons who are neither students or instructors.

Here are the tables (they are all populated with values that fit all criteria):

```
    CREATE TABLE Person (
    Name char (20),
    ID char (9) not null,
    Address char (30),
    DOB date,
    Primary key (ID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Instructor (
    InstructorID char (9) not null references Person (ID),
    Rank char (12),
    Salary integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (InstructorID)
    );

    CREATE TABLE Student (
      StudentID char (9) not null REFERENCES Person (ID),
      Classification char (10),
      GPA DOUBLE,
      MentorID char (9) REFERENCES Instructor (InstructorID),
      CreditHours integer,
      PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
    );
```

And here is my answer/query:

```
    SELECT Person.ID, Person.Name, Person.DOB
    FROM Person
    RIGHT JOIN Student ON Person.ID = Student.StudentID
    RIGHT JOIN Instructor ON Person.ID = Instructor.InstructorID
    WHERE NOT Person.ID = Student.StudentID AND Person.ID = 
              Instructor.InstructorID;
```

Did I screw up something on my joins? I'm not getting any errors, but the query isn't returning anything either. I've tried all joins (left, right, full) to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use NOT IN to determine if the records are not in both of those tables

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       dob
  FROM Person
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT studentid
                    FROM student)
   AND id NOT IN (SELECT instructorid
                    FROM instructor);
```

Comment: it's not about if there's data showing up, it's about if the expected data is not showing up. try to determine first the data/record you expected to show

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close.  First, use `LEFT JOIN` so you keep everything in the first table.  Second, use comparisons to `NULL` to see if there are matches:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p.DOB
FROM Person p LEFT JOIN
     Student s
     ON p.ID = s.StudentID LEFT JOIN
     Instructor i
     ON p.ID = i.InstructorID
WHERE s.StudentID IS NULL AND i.InstructorID IS NULL;
```